# PhpStorm Clipboard API

Tags: javascript, phpstorm, webstorm

I'm trying to use the `Clipboard API` which already works in browsers, but PhpStorm doesn't know of it.

[image]

What does it take to make PhpStorm recognise it? I've set the JavaScript-language version in the project-settings to `ECMAScript 6`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Lena for the right direction, I've found a way so sort it.

Under `Settings > Javascript > Libraries` click on `Download`. Select  `dom-clipboard-api` from the list and click `download and install`.

The library stub consists of this: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/dom-clipboard-api/index.d.ts

I needed to invalidate caches and restart PhpStorm, but afterwards it worked as I expected.

Answer (score 1):

PhpStorm uses library definitions stubs from https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/tree/master/lib for Web APIs support. Unfortunately no library stubs are available for this API, as it's not yet  widely adopted. Please see https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26728#issuecomment-422970152 for possible workaround

Comment: How do you know the https://github.com/Microsoft/* URL? I've never seen it anywhere. Is it hard-coded?

Comment: haven't got what you mean... This is Typescript compiler repository; and we don't use this URL anywhere, lid.d.ts files from this repo are bundled with PhpStorm as a part of JavaScriptLanguage plugin